# get online users + acegi-security

Tags: spring-security

How do i get users connected to my site
iam using spring + acegi

Answer (score 4):

Below I'm talking about spring-security (because acegi-security is now spring-security and I assumed that you use spring-security). Moreover I have tested this configuration with the lastest version of spring security

---

Search into : [SessionRegistry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html)

Related to : [security-session-management](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html)

on **web.xml**

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
</listener>
```

on spring security xml file example **app-security.xml**

Focus on security:session-management and the last two beans

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user*" access="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/register.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/activate.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />     
        <security:form-login login-page="/user/login.html" default-target-url="/index.html" authentication-failure-url="/user/login.html" />
        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/index.html" />
        <security:remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/user/logout.html" invalidate-session="false" />
</security:http>

<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</bean>
```

then in code/controller

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistry;
...
List<Object> allPrincipals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
...
```

allPrincipals containts all the online users